# Apache2.4 + mod_wsgi, security

Tags: apache, security, mod-wsgi

How can I protect a django application with apache + mod_wsgi from DOS style attacks, similar to "slowloris"? With the default apache settings, a simple slowloris/DDOS attack freezes my apache server.
How apache should be configured for security?
I'm talking **only** on apache and web server related security issues, and not on code related ones (such as SQL injection, XSS..)

Comment: Have you looked at mod_ratelimit? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ratelimit.html For other styles of DOS attacks besides plane connect attacks, there are various settings you can use in mod_wsgi daemon mode. In short there are lots of ways to do DOS attacks so how exactly are you testing this.

Comment: I'm curious as well about how to defend against this type of DoS attack (request body slowloris attack for example). Something like the attack described here https://www.blackmoreops.com/2015/06/07/attack-website-using-slowhttptest-in-kali-linux/ with just a few requests equal to the number of threads configured on the wsgi_daemon can easily block the whole server until either apache timeout happens, or RequestReadTimeout happens or w/e proxy/load balancer (such as aws one) you have in front kills the connection. A large number of requests can be used to lock the server permanently